# Python audio Mpylayer with mplayer

Tags: python, loops, audio

Hi all brand new to Python, I am working on a script that plays some audio for me via GPIO triggers. Script works great, only thing is I want the audio to loop.

I am using a Python plugin called Mpylayer.

In a simplified version of what I have, this is where I am stuck,

```
 Mp1 = mpylayer.MPlayerControl()
 Mp1.loadfile('/path/to/audio.wav')
 Mp1.loop = 1
```

And then in a separate function/GPIO trigger I have,

```
Mp1.quit()
```

Ideally the audio would loop forever, till the quit trigger. Again, that part works great, it's just the getting it to loop part. The docs for the plugin seem to say there is a way to do it, but if hit a roadblock.

Thanks for any help!

--Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Mp1 = mpylayer.MPlayerControl()

Mp1.loadfile('/path/to/audio.wav')

Mp1.loop = 0
```

It will loop for ever if you give the value 0.